# Rails get all records except ones with certain relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

**Video.rb**

```
has_many :categories
```

**Category.rb**

```
has_many :videos
```

I want to retrive all videos excepts the ones with certain category. Something like this.

**Video.where("category != ?", 13)**

Is there a way how to perform query like this? This is obviously wrong query.

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is the not condition.
Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions

code example

```
Video.where.not(category: 13)
```

Comment: but I don't have "category" column in "videos" table, because video can have many categories.